# How to extract formula and subset information from a function call

Tags: r, survival-analysis

In my current work I often use survfit() to calculate the Kaplan-Meier estimate for survival data, and do the log-rank test using survdiff().

I would like to know how I could extract the formula and subset information from a survfit() call and input it directly into survdiff(). I usually use

```
survdiff(formula(survfit.object))
```

but this wont recognize any subset argument provided in my survfit call.

For example:

```
library(survival)

fail.time <- 12*rexp(100)
group <- factor(sample(1:3,100,replace=TRUE),1:3,c('a','b','c'))
fail.status <- rbinom(100,1,0.4)

srv<-survfit(Surv(fail.time,fail.status)~group,subset=group!="a")
survdiff(formula(srv))
```

which isn't what I want, rather I'd like

```
survdiff(formula(srv),subset=group!="a")
```

but I'm hoping to find a method which will allow me to not have to add the subset information again.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most model fitting objects in R store the entire call:

```
survdiff(formula(srv),subset = srv$call$subset)
```

or just:

```
eval(srv$call)
```

which re-runs the original call in its entirety.

Comment: Your subset = srv$call$subset seems clear to me, but could you elaborate on the eval(srv$call) comment? I'm unable to reproduce the results from survdiff(formula(srv),subset=group!="a") using eval(). You get up-boats for the help though!

Comment: @SteveReno Not sure exactly what you're running into. When I run `all.equal(srv,eval(srv$call))` I get `TRUE`.

Comment: correct, eval(srv$call) will return the same values as the survfit() call, but I am interested in using survdiff() on srv$call. I'm unclear as to how I can use eval() to get the same results as survdiff(formula(srv),subset = srv$call$subset) for example

Comment: @SteveReno I only pointed out the use of `eval` because in your particular example you were literally replicating the original call. If you only want to use parts of the original call you'll need to extract the pieces you need.

Comment: understood, I interpreted your response as I could just use eval() instead of the first answer given. Thanks again!